# How to link Connection to Refresh Table in VBA

Tags: database, vba, excel, connection

I need to refresh a number of connections in Excel, without storing the password in the connection details. I am using a VBA script to attempt this. My code is:

```
Sub Test() 
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

' Connection string information for  DB as a variable (strCon)

strCon = "Driver={dummy}; " & _
"CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=" & _
"(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=dummy)" & _
"(HOST=dummy)(PORT=dummy))" & _
"(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME = dummy))); uid=dummy; pwd=dummy;"

' Opens the above connection string.
con.Open (strCon)

ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

My code seems to open a connection, and refreshes the tables. However, it is still asking for me to input a password. How do I use the open connection to refresh the tables?

Comment: Here's another question that is pretty much identical.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20416105/excel-vba-data-connection-password

Comment: Thanks, however that doesn't specifically tell me how to link the two together (I'm a beginner VBA level).

Comment: why don't you save the password as string dim psswd as string psswed = "Dummy" and try to use that variable in the connection string? where you specify pwd=dummy.......... I'm not sure just a thought.

Comment: I think the connection itself is working. I just don't know how to link it into my ActiveWorkbook piece ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to delete my connections in the database and use VBA code to replicate my connections in a series of SQL queries. The basis of the code that I am using is:

```
'Declare variables'
    Set objMyConn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String

'Open Connection'
    objMyConn.ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; " & _
"CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=" & _
"(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=***)" & _
"(HOST=*****)(PORT=****))" & _
"(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME = ****))); uid=****; pwd=*****;"
objMyConn.Open

'Set and Excecute SQL Command'
    strSQL = "Select distinct * From Temp_Final_Complaints_Report"

'Open Recordset'
    Set objMyRecordset.ActiveConnection = objMyConn
    objMyRecordset.Open strSQL

'Copy Data to Excel'
    Sheets("Complaints Report").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset (objMyRecordset)
```

I can now encrypt the module where this is saved with a password.